What would happen if there were nine lunar cycles in a year?
I'm working on an alternative Earth, where (at least) one country would divide the ~365-day year into nine months of approximately 40 days, and I would like the months to be calculated according to the cycles of the moon. A lunisolar calendar would work perfectly for my world, because people there worship both the sun and the moon. But, as the world is very similar to our Earth, I started wondering if having nine lunar months would have a big effect on e.g. harvests, tides, or general way of life.
Would having nine lunar months have any major effect on life in general, if the year is the same length as ours and seasons change similarly to ours? If it would have an effect, what kind?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

What affect do you think it will have? Is there something specific you want to ask about instead of asking an open ended what could happen?

Maybe you should look up the Sliding Scale of Science fiction Hardness.
https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/MediaNotes/MohsScaleOfScienceFictionHardness
And then decide what score on that scale you want for your story.  If you are content with a very low score, then you can ignore what follows.  If you desire a higher score, then read on.
Perhaps you should consider the Hill sphere radius of a planet orbiting a star.

The Hill sphere is a common model for the calculation of a gravitational sphere of influence. It is the most commonly used model to calculate the spatial extent of gravitational influence of an astronomical body (m) in which it dominates over the gravitational influence of other bodies, particularly a primary (M).2

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_sphere#

In the Earth-Sun example, the Earth (5.97×1024 kg) orbits the Sun (1.99×1030 kg) at a distance of 149.6 million km, or one astronomical unit (AU). The Hill sphere for Earth thus extends out to about 1.5 million km (0.01 AU). The Moon's orbit, at a distance of 0.384 million km from Earth, is comfortably within the gravitational sphere of influence of Earth and it is therefore not at risk of being pulled into an independent orbit around the Sun.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_sphere#Example_and_derivation

The Hill sphere is only an approximation, and other forces (such as radiation pressure or the Yarkovsky effect) can eventually perturb an object out of the sphere.[citation needed] As stated, the satellite (third mass) should be small enough that its gravity contributes negligibly.4: p.26ff


The Hill sphere is only an approximation, and other forces (such as radiation pressure or the Yarkovsky effect) can eventually perturb an object out of the sphere.[citation needed] As stated, the satellite (third mass) should be small enough that its gravity contributes negligibly.4: p.26ff
Detailed numerical calculations show that orbits at or just within the Hill sphere are not stable in the long term; it appears that stable satellite orbits exist only inside 1/2 to 1/3 of the Hill radius.[citation needed]
The region of stability for retrograde orbits at a large distance from the primary is larger than the region for prograde orbits at a large distance from the primary. This was thought to explain the preponderance of retrograde moons around Jupiter; however, Saturn has a more even mix of retrograde/prograde moons so the reasons are more complicated.[10]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_sphere#Regions_of_stability
I have read something else about the limits of the orbits of moons of planets.
In "Exomoon habitability constrained by illumination and tidal heating" by Rene Heller and Rory Barnes, 2013.
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.5323
The article is about the hypothetical habitability of hypothetical exomoons of planets in other star systems.  And the discussion is about habitability for liquid water using lifeforms in general and not for the more restricted habitability for humans and lifeforms with similar environmental requirements.
Since an exomoon of a giant planet will probably be tidally locked to the planet it orbits, its day (cycle of light and dark) will be equal to its orbital period around the planet.
On page 3 it is said:

The longest possible length of a satellite’s day compatible with Hill stability has been shown to be about P∗p/9, P∗p being the
planet’s orbital period about the star (Kipping 2009a).

And that means that the longest orbital period of a moon around its planet consistent with orbital stability will be about one/ninth as long as the planet's orbital period around the star.
And in your question you say:

I'm working on an alternative Earth, where (at least) one country would divide the ~365-day year into nine months of approximately 40 days, and I would like the months to be calculated according to the cycles of the moon.
So the orbital period of the moon would be about one/ninth as long as the orbital period of the planet around its star.  And so it would be on the edge of having an unstable orbit and escaping from the planet.  Once the moon escaped from the planet it would take a similar orbit around the star, and possibly eventually collide with the planet with disastrous results, and unless it was ejected from the system first.

As it happens a large moon of a planet have strong tidal interactions with the planet and over millions and billions of years those tidal interactions will slow down the rotation of the planet, making its day longer, and slow down the rotation period of the moon until it is tidally locked with the planet.  And they will also push the moon father and farther away from the planet.
If you want the month to be about 40 Earth days long, the moon will have to be orbiting the planet at the right distance to have an orbital period of 40 Earth  days.
So I went to this online orbital period calculator:
https://www.calctool.org/astrophysics/orbital-period
And made the mass of the planet 1 Earth mass and the mass of the moon 0.0123 that of the Earth, which is the mass of the Moon. And the first semi-major axis for the orbit of the fictional moon I selected was 500,000 kilometers, and the orbital period came to 40 days and 11 hours.
A semi-major axis of 490,000 kilometers gave a period of 39 days and 6 hours, while a semi-major axis of 499,000 kilometers gave a period of 40 days and 8 hours, and a semi-major axis of 498,000 kilometers gave a period of 40 days and 5 hours.
Such a semi-major axis would be considerably larger than the present semi-major axis of the Moon's orbit, 384,399 kilometers.  Since the region of true orbital stability around the Earth only extends to about 500,000 to 750,000 kilometers, the Moon with an orbital period of 40 Earth days would be close to the edge of the zone of stability.
And forces which pushed the Moon that much farther from Earth should also have made Earth's day longer, so that 40 Earth days in that period would be much longer than 40 present Earth days, so the Moon would be orbiting even farther from Earth.
Unless the days are longer and maybe there are 25, 30, or 35 days in a month in their calendar, equal to about 40 present Earth days.
Thus I can believe that in the setting you desire, someone could calculate that the Moon will escape from Earth orbit and go into orbit around the Sun in about one hundred million years, or one million years, or ten thousand years, or one hundred years, or one year, depending on the plot.  And maybe they might calculate that the Moon would then collide with the Earth in one million years or ten years, depending on the plot.
You should also consider the differences between different types of years, months, and days.

Each of these three years can be loosely called an astronomical year.
The sidereal year is the time taken for the Earth to complete one revolution of its orbit, as measured against a fixed frame of reference (such as the fixed stars, Latin sidera, singular sidus). Its average duration is 365.256363004 days (365 d 6 h 9 min 9.76 s) (at the epoch J2000.0 = January 1, 2000, 12:00:00 TT).9
Today the mean tropical year is defined as the period of time for the mean ecliptic longitude of the Sun to increase by 360 degrees.[10] Since the Sun's ecliptic longitude is measured with respect to the equinox,[11] the tropical year comprises a complete cycle of the seasons and is the basis of solar calendars such as the internationally used Gregorian calendar. The modern definition of mean tropical year differs from the actual time between passages of, e.g., the northward equinox, by a minute or two, for several reasons explained below. Because of the Earth's axial precession, this year is about 20 minutes shorter than the sidereal year. The mean tropical year is approximately 365 days, 5 hours, 48 minutes, 45 seconds, using the modern definition[12] ( = 365.24219 d × 86 400 s). The length of the tropical year varies a bit over thousands of years because the rate of axial precession is not constant.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year#Sidereal,_tropical,_and_anomalistic_years

The sidereal month is defined as the Moon's orbital period in a non-rotating frame of reference (which on average is equal to its rotation period in the same frame). It is about 27.32166 days (27 days, 7 hours, 43 minutes, 11.6 seconds). It is closely equal to the time it takes the Moon to twice pass a "fixed" star (different stars give different results because all have a very small proper motion and are not really fixed in position).
A synodic month is the most familiar lunar cycle, defined as the time interval between two consecutive occurrences of a particular phase (such as new moon or full moon) as seen by an observer on Earth. The mean length of the synodic month is 29.53059 days (29 days, 12 hours, 44 minutes, 2.8 seconds). Due to the eccentricity of the lunar orbit around Earth (and to a lesser degree, the Earth's elliptical orbit around the Sun), the length of a synodic month can vary by up to seven hours.

So the sidereal year and sidereal month are important for calculating  whether the Moon's orbit is stable.
But the tropical year and the synodic month are used in designing calendars.

A sidereal day or stellar day is the span of time it takes for the Earth to make one entire rotation6 with respect to the celestial background or a distant star (assumed to be fixed).7 Measuring a day as such is used in astronomy.7 A sidereal day is about 4 minutes less than a solar day of 24 hours (23 hours 56 minutes and 4.09 seconds), or 0.99726968 of a solar day of 24 hours.8 There are about 366.2422 stellar days in one mean tropical year (one stellar day more than the number of solar days).9

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day#Sidereal_day
A solar day is the time it takes the Earth to rotate 360 degrees with respect to the Sun.  Solar days are used in making calendars.
You wrote:

I'm working on an alternative Earth, where (at least) one country would divide the ~365-day year into nine months of approximately 40 days, and I would like the months to be calculated according to the cycles of the moon.

And that indicates that the star should be the Sun, the planet the Earth, and the moon the Moon, but in an alternate universe where events were different, giving the moon a longer orbital period.
The present theory about the formation of the of the Moon is that there was a Mars sized planet, named "Theia" in an orbit similar to Earth's orbit.  And eventually Theia collided with the Earth and mostly merged into Earth, which was turned molten for millions of years after the collision.
And a lot of debris was thrown into orbit around the Earth, forming a ring.   and the ring material gradually clumped together to form the Moon.  And tidal interactions between the Earth and the Moon slowed down the rotation of the Earth and the Moon and drove the Moon much farther from the Earth over billions of years.
And so you want something to be different in an alternate universe to drive the Moon much farther from the Earth without making Earth days much longer than they are.
So maybe a super advanced group of aliens visiting earth found a way to move the moon much father from Earth without making Earth days much longer than they are today.
And if you want a natural explanation, possibly the collision between Earth and Theia was different in some way, enough to change the history of the Moon.
PlanetPlanet.net is a blog site of Astrophysicist Sean Raymond.  And he says he is available to help with worldbuilding for science fiction stories.
https://planetplanet.net/about/
His job is running calculations and simulations to test theories of the formation of solar systems.
So maybe he can suggest a way to get the Moon to have a month about 40 days long.
And some versions of the giant impact theory indicate that Earth once had two moons, formed out of the ring of debris, which later merged.  Possibly if things were different somehow, the two moons would not have merged but would have remained separate and moved away from Earth with different speeds, and thus would have different orbits and different month lengths.
And possibly there could be a 40 day period between successive times when the two moons were in the same direction relative to the Sun and thus had the same phase.

Probably lower tides
Assuming that this alternate Earth does not dramatically change the gravitational constant or the value of pi, the orbital period of this Earth's moon is dependent on two values that could theoretically change:

The mass of the more massive body (ie Earth); and/or
The radius of the moon's orbit.

Further assuming that you do not want to change the mass of the Earth (in order to not mess with surface gravity and/or geological structure), the only real option is to increase the radius of the moon's orbit.  Increasing the radius by 20% will increase the orbital period by slighly over 30%, which gets into the ballpark of the 40ish day orbital period you are looking for.
If you have alternate-Earth's moon being physically the same as real-Earth's moon, just orbiting 20% further out, then the moon's gravitational influence on alternate-Earth will be about 70% of what real-Earth experiences.  This would noticeably reduce the height of tidal action and would undoubtedly have some effect on weather systems, probably reducing the energy of some of them, but modelling that would be ridiculously difficult.  Putting an object the same size 20% further away will also, obviously, make it apparently smaller to observers on Earth.
(You could increase the mass of the alternate-Earth's moon in order to keep the tides the same height, but that could have all kinds of undesirable effects - our moon is pretty big already relative to the size of Earth and you don't want to tidally lock the Earth to the moon unless you want alternate-Earth to have days that are 40 real-Earth days long.)
At a simplistic level, that's all.  The length and intensity of seasons experienced on Earth etc are all dependent on Earth's orbit around the sun, so moving the moon a bit further out has no effect.  If the Earth is still rotating at the same speed then the frequency of tides will not have changed either, only their magnitude.  (At the ludicrously detailed level, having the moon 20% further out would mean Earth had a completely different planetary and geological history, but this can be safely disregarded.)  Naturally it would also have an effect on space travel - you should ask a separate question if you wish to explore those effects.
